# Is it possible to insert more than 25 items on DynamoDB using BatchPutItem (BatchWriteItem) using AppSync VTL?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-dynamodb, apollo, aws-appsync, vtl

Just for some context: Currently using AppSync + React + Apollo, and I'm trying to send 38 - 40 items to update via AppSync's Apache VTL.

I knew that DynamoDB limited the number of items inserted to [25 per request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html), but I thought AppSync didn't have those limitations. Guess I'm wrong, because my request fails whenever I send more than 25 items (26+).

Here's my VTL script:

```java
#set($isTenantValid = false)
#foreach($tenant in $context.identity.claims["https://app.schon.io/tenants"])
    #if($tenant == $ctx.args.tenantId)
        #set($isTenantValid = true)
    #end
#end

## Needs to verify if the employee has permission to insert students.

#if(!$isTenantValid) 
    $utils.unauthorized()
#end


#set($itemsToPut=[])
#set($pk="tenant:${ctx.args.tenantId}")
#set($userSK="tenant:${ctx.args.tenantId}:school-year:${ctx.args.schoolYear}")

#foreach($student in $ctx.args.students)
    #set($studentId = "${util.autoId()}")
    #set($sk="school-year:${ctx.args.schoolYear}:student:${studentId}")
    #set($userPK="student:${studentId}")

    #set($item = {
    "pk": $pk,
    "sk": $sk,
    "id": $studentId,
    "userPK": $userPK,
    "userSK": $userSK,
    "name": {
        "firstName" : $student.name.firstName,
        "lastName" : $student.name.lastName,
        "fullName": "${student.name.firstName} ${student.name.lastName}"
    },
    "schoolYear": $ctx.args.schoolYear,
    "createdAt": ${util.time.nowEpochSeconds()},
    "updatedAt": ${util.time.nowEpochSeconds()},
    "gender": $student.gender,
    "retired": $student.retired
    })
    #if("${student.diseases}" != "")
        $util.qr($item.add("diseases", $student.diseases)) 
    #end
    #if("${student.email}" != "")
        $util.qr($item.add("email", $student.email)) 
    #end
    #if("${student.birthdate}" != "")
        $util.qr($item.add("birthdate", $student.birthdate)) 
    #end

    $util.qr($itemsToPut.add($util.dynamodb.toMapValues($item)))
#end


{
    "version" : "2018-05-29",
    "operation" : "BatchPutItem",
    "tables" : {
        "SchonDB": $utils.toJson($itemsToPut)
    }
}
```

In this case, will I need to offload it to a Lambda and do the send and retry logic per 25 items?

Comment: It depends on your DDB's write capacity units (WCUs) and payload size.

Comment: @JosephD. Is it possible? The docs explicitly say: "A single call to BatchWriteItem can write up to 16 MB of data, which can comprise as many as 25 put or delete requests." I also have DynamoDB to auto-provision the WCUs and RCUs

Comment: No. See [API Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to contact DDB team to increase service limit for you?

Comment: You mean Amazon Web Services AWS?

Comment: Yes AWS customer support.

Comment: Sorry for never coming back! I ended up going deploying it via a lambda resolver instead! So I never contacted AWS.

Comment: @JoseA can you share the resolver for batch inserting more than 25 items?

Comment: Hi @KhaderMA. The only way is to do this through AWS Lambda. There's no way to do it through AppSync.You need to create a Lambda resolver and then use the AWS SDK to insert it.